# RSS Feed disappears on Postback in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rss

I have an asp.net page which shows an RSS feed generated using feed2js.org site. It provides javascript code to be put on the webpage inside the tags where you want to show the feed. For example I wanted the feed to show in table so I put the javascript inside the `<td>` tags:

```
<td style="padding: 5px; font-size: 15px;" runat="server" id="tabCol">
script language=\"JavaScript\" src=\"http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.medicalnewstoday.com%2Frss%2Fpharmacy.xml&num=1&targ=y&utf=y\" charset=\"UTF-8\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
</td>
```

The page works fine when it first loads and shows the feed but when I click a button on the page the feed disappears. Can someone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: The markup you've provided for your script is escaped as if it's a javascript string and is missing the opening `<`. Are you sure you shouldn't be using `<script src="http://feed2js.org/feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.medicalnewstoday.com%2Frss%2Fpharmacy.xml&num=1&targ=y&utf=y" charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>` (ignoring the space that SO is inserting automatically in the `src` value)?

Comment: Is your postback taking place within an `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all those unnecessary backslash, if by some chance you inject the script tag with a javascript function, you need to make sure it render the script tag correctly

```
<td style="padding: 5px; font-size: 15px;" runat="server" id="tabCol">
  <script src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.medicalnewstoday.com%2Frss%2Fpharmacy.xml&num=1&targ=y&utf=y" charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</td>
```